# Нужнен код который будет заменять слово "кот" на рандомное слово из списка, так чтобы 1 кот и 2 кот могли замениться как на одно так и на разные слова

Tags: python, replace, замена, случайные-числа

```
import random

string = '''кот вышел на улицу,
кот залез на дерево,
ночью кот бегал по дому,
кот ходит по лужайке,
кот встретил друга,
кот любит быть дома.
'''

zamena = ["пёс", "хомяк"]

x = random.randint(0, len(zamena) - 1)

string1 = string.replace("кот", zamena[x])

print(string1)
```

*// данный код заменяет всех котов в тексте либо на хомяков, либо на псов, необходим полный рандом для каждого слова "кот", без дублирования рандома после второй строки //*

Answer (score 5):

```
import random

string = '''кот вышел на улицу,
кот залез на дерево,
ночью кот бегал по дому,
кот ходит по лужайке,
кот встретил друга,
кот любит быть дома.
'''

zamena = ["пёс", "хомяк"]
string1 = string

while "кот" in string1:
    string1 = string1.replace("кот", random.choice(zamena), 1)

print(string1)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь. Вы очень помогли :)

Comment: Галочку можно ставить, если вопрос решен

Answer (score 1):

метод sub в модуле re позволяет использовать в качестве строки замены результат выполнения функции

```
import random
import re

string = '''кот вышел на улицу,
кот залез на дерево,
ночью кот бегал по дому,
кот ходит по лужайке,
кот встретил друга,
кот любит быть дома.
'''

zamena = ["пёс", "хомяк"]

string1 = re.sub("кот", lambda i: random.choice(zamena), string)

print(string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

string = '''кот вышел на улицу,
кот залез на дерево,
ночью кот бегал по дому,
кот ходит по лужайке,
кот встретил друга,
кот любит быть дома.
'''
string1 = ''
zamena = ["пёс", "хомяк"]
for z in string.split('\n'):
    x = random.choice(zamena)
    string1 += z.replace("кот", x) + '\n'
print(string1)

# 2
string1 = string
for z in range(string.count("кот")):
    x = random.choice(zamena)
    string1 = string1.replace("кот", x, 1)

print(string1)
```

Comment: а если 2 кота в одной строке?

Comment: В данной задаче нет двух котов в строке))